# how to show fatched data in div from laravel controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am making custom chat system using laravel ajax.my data is coming successfully in console.I want to show this data in my div.
here is my ajax code...

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/home/admin_comment_get",
  data: {
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    seventh_id: seventhid,
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (res) {
    // console.log(res.comments)
    let html = "";
    $.each(res.comments, function (key, value) {});
  },
});
```

and here is my view blade

```html
<div class="fatch_comment">
  <div class="outgoing_msg" id="outgoing">
    <div class="sent_msg">
      <p class="message"></p>
      <span class="time_date"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="incoming_msg">
    <div class="incoming_msg_img">
      <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil">
    </div>
    <div class="received_msg">
      <div class="received_withd_msg">
        <p>sfsdfsdfs</p>
        <span class="time_date"> 444</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to loop this `fatch_comment`.

- if status is 1 then it show in `outgoing`
- if status is 0 it show in `incoming_msg`

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?  This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Laravel or PHP, just JavaScript and HTML.  If you've successfully received data from the server, what's stopping you from displaying that data on the page?

Comment: yes i received data successfully from server...but I want to append or prepend my div with this data. thats mean i want to view this data to my div outgoing and incoming_msg

Comment: *"but I want to append or prepend my div with this data"* - Have you tried doing that?  What specifically didn't work as expected?  If you're looking for how to append an element with jQuery, or how to set the text of an element with jQuery, or any other similar operation then your favorite search engine should be able to find some *pretty aptly named* functions in jQuery for performing those operations.

Comment: acctually i am new in ajax. i did this in table...but i cannot do it in div...i dont understand how can i view and loop data in these div... I did till all data are coming from server.... so that i need help how to view this data in those div

Comment: It doesn't sound like AJAX really has anything to do with it.  If you have the data you need then the AJAX operation has already completed.  It sounds like you're just asking how to update the page with the data you have.  What specific update are you trying to make, and what specific data are you using to make that update?  What stops you from, for example, selecting an element with jQuery and setting the `html()` or `text()` of that element?  Or creating an element to `append()` or `prepend()` to another element?

Comment: success: function (res){
                    // console.log(res.comments)
                    let html = "";
                    
                    $.each(res.comments, function (key, value){
                      html += `<p> ${ value.body }</p>`,
                      html += `<span> ${ value.created_at }</span>`
                    });
                    $('.message').html(html);
                    $('.admin_date').html(html);
                      
                }

Comment: i am trying this. but it showing my data double

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "showing my data double"?  This operation: `$('.message').html(html);` will set the HTML of every matching `.message` element.  If you have two such elements, they will both be updated.  Is that what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with Laravel component

```
php artisan make:component Comment
```

it will create a component into view->components->Comment.blade.php directory

```
 <div class="fatch_comment">
  @if(count($comment)> 0)
    @if($comment.status == 1)
    <div class="outgoing_msg" id="outgoing">
      <div class="sent_msg">
        <p class="message">{{$comment->time_date}}</p>
        <span class="time_date"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    @elseif($comment.status == 0)
    <div class="incoming_msg">
      <div class="incoming_msg_img">
        <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil">
      </div>
      <div class="received_msg">
        <div class="received_withd_msg">
          <p>{{$comment->message}}</p> // replace with your parameter name
          <span class="time_date"> {{$comment->time_date}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endif
  @endif
</div>
```

and your controller logic will be look like this

```
 public function admin_comment_get(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $output="";
            $comments=UserCommet::where('seventh_id',$request->seventh_id)->get();
            if($comments)
            {
            foreach ($comments as $key => $comment) {
                $output .= View::make("components.comment")
                    ->with("comment", $comment)
                    ->render();
                }
            return Response($output);
            }
        }
    }
```

and your script look like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/home/admin_comment_get",
  data: {
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    seventh_id: seventhid,
  },
  success: function (res) {
    // console.log(res.comments)
    $('tbody').html(res); //replace your div tag  
  },
});
```

Comment: did not know you can do this. haha. all those wasted efforts to document.createElement. the nightmare ! good to know.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth but he wants rendered from controller

Comment: I did not try this yet but at first glance it should be what he wants if he wants to load the items from controller/blade